# AngularJS - Erroneously Refreshing DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I've found a rather complex issue with my angularJS SPA website that I can't seem to find a solution for. When I go to the page for the first time (in chrome incognito mode), everything loads fine. However, when I click on a button to go to another page on my site, the DOM gets reloaded. This is a problem because I have some local values that I need to retain their values. I can't pinpoint an exact area in my code that's causing this to happen. Has anyone else had this problem before? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What does the button code look like? You could try to use an ng-click function and $location.path() instead of button / a tag html functionality

Comment: Can you post the code for the button in question so we can confirm the above comment

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).